# How to use variable range in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, countif, named-ranges

Currently I have such formula:
`COUNTIFS(B3:B36,"16",E3:E36,"01")`

Would it be possible to turn these ranges `B3:B36` and `E3:E36` into variables, like B'start_cell_value':B'stop_cell_value'.

The whole thing would look like:

```
 =COUNTIFS(B'start_cell_value':B'stop_cell_value',"16",E'start_cell_value':E'stop_cell_value',"01")
```

`start_cell_value` and `stop_cell_value` are just some numbers stored in a separate cell. This would help, since changing numbers in those cells only would also change everything in the formula and that's exactly what I want.

I have tried to combine a numeric value from other cells with a letter to make a valid cell name but it doesn't seem to work or it just throws a reference error.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with Named Ranges you can have it even exact:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("B"&start_cell_value&":B"&stop_cell_value), "16", 
          INDIRECT("E"&start_cell_value&":E"&stop_cell_value), "01")
```

[image]

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("B"&A1&":B"&A2), "16",
          INDIRECT("E"&A1&":E"&A2), "01")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you have the start_cell_value in cell A1 and the stop_cell_value in A2 then try this formula:

`=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("B"&A1&":B"&A2),"16",INDIRECT("E"&A1&":E"&A2),"01")`